# Files button on the side opens a new window instead of minimized window?

Tags: 13.04, filesystem, files

If I open my hard drive from the hard drive icon (I have 2 hard drives) and then I minimize it, it minimizes to the files and when I try to restore it it opens a new file manager (this happens weather I open the drive from the file manager itself or if I open the drive from the Unity bar). In order to get back I need to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. Is there a way to fix this (Ubuntu 13.04 the best release ever)

Comment: There's a confirmed open bug for this problem: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1170647

Answer (score 4):

I think this is a bug. It only happens (at least, for me) when Nautilus is viewing files on a separate drive (like an external drive, or a memory card).

There is a workaround until this is fixed though. All you have to do is simply hover your mouse over the "Files" icon in launcher, and scroll up or down. If you have more than one window open, it will scroll between them. This, I find, is a lot faster than using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

[This is a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1170647) that has been around for a long time. But if you Unlock "Files" from the launcher, it seems to work just fine.

@aikikode, Scrolling to focus seems to be removed in the 14.04 Beta-1. It is said that it is not in the design, so they removed it. But [another bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1288957) suggests they should add it as an option and they probably will in the final release.

Answer (score -1):

Could you be more specific: how do you minimize and restore it? By clicking hard drive icon or 'Files' icon? Left or right mouse button with selecting it from drop down list?

In my case LMB click either on 'Files' or 'Hard Drive' icon restores the same window.

Maybe try to install all the system updates:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```